# make my html website send notifications

Tags: android, web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i want to write some code in my website that will allow me to send messages to a my android app. i know about gcm and that tells me what to do to get my app side of things ready to receive the notification. But it doesnt tell me how to implement this into my website. i want to be able to send an appointment date and time to my app.
so i can create the part in my website to set the date and time of the appointment and i can create a send button. But when i press the send button nothing is going to happen. so say if i have 6 android devices that have this app that recieves notifications. i want to select one device with my website and send it to that device with my website.

can i have a detailed answer as i am a serious novice and some links. ps i know about gcm but maybe i do not understand it properly becuase i cant see were it helps me with my website side of things i can only see where it helps on the application side of things. if you think different then show me please even paste the code in your answer.
thank you

Comment: no I didnt paste my code but I help you solving the problem with your code...

Comment: there isnt a problem with my code i just want to know how to implement the push notification into my website if you dont want to give me code tell me were to go to solve my problem. i know about the app side of things just not my website side of things

Comment: try reading the docs: [GCM: Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app)